# Batch - Separated Commands

Tags: batch-file

can someone say me how do a thing?

```
:oof
set /p choose= 
if %chose% == help 2 goto help2
:help2
echo lol
goto oof
```

But when I wrote help 2 the program closed and I didn't understand why
i tried to do this by adding ""

```
:oof
set /p choose= 
if %chose% == "help 2" goto help2
:help2
echo lol
goto oof
```

but it still didn't work, I can't understand why but wasn't enough to solve my problem.

Comment: Remember that variables are expanded (replaced by their values) before the parser even tries to execute anything. With that in mind, it should be obvious that the variable has to be quoted too. (besides that, the quotes are compared too, so `if A == "A"` will never be true)

Comment: Please also note that your comparisons will still fail if you continue to use `%chose%` instead of `%choose%`. _(Alternatively you could use `set /p chose=` instead of `set /p choose=`)_.